# Getting nil when preparing for segue to navigation controller

Tags: xcode, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have found a few other questions about this same topic, so this is technically a repost, however the solutions provided there are not helping me at all. The solutions that have been suggested, which seem to work for the other users, are already present in my code.

Here is the code that is causing me problems.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    let navView = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
    let destinationView = navView.topViewController as DetailViewController
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The error is thrown on the error where I am accessing navView.topViewController.

I have a table view segueing to a navigation controller, which then segues to my own custom view controller under it. I want to pass data to my custom view controller from the table view.

I had it working fine earlier today before adding the navigation controller in between, passing data directly from the table view to the navigation controller. Adding the navigation controller in between has broken things.

Are there any suggestions as to why I am having this problem? The only thing I can think is that the DetailViewController hasn't instantiated yet since it is two levels deep now. But then if that is the case, I don't know why it seems to be working for other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a table view segueing to a navigation controller, **which then segues to my own custom view controller under it**.

I believe that is your problem.  The connection from the Navigation Controller to your Detail View Controller isn't a normal segue.  It should be a Relationship Segue.

1. Click on the connection between the Navigation Controller and the Detail View Controller.  Press <kbd>delete</kbd>.
2. <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from the Navigation Controller to the Detail View Controller and select **root view controller** from the pop up.

Now `navView.topViewController` will be non-nil.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I did that. Was scratching my head over this for a few hours. I should have known better.